# how does jsoup selector works?

Tags: java, jsoup

`Elements divs =  doc.select("#mp-itn b a");`

In this the `mp-itn` is the id of a div tag. What is this b and a?
what does it signify?

I am not able understand this. Please let me know some good tutorials on jsoup.

Comment: Tutorials: [Jsoup cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/), and [Selector API](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Comment: Jsoup selectors are very similar to CSS selectors, which have a lot more resources to look at.  The basic functionality is all duplicated in Jsoup.

Answer (score 1):

They refer to link tag `<a ...></a>` and bold tag `<b></b>`. So in that example it selects the `a` tags within bold tags within the tag that has an id of `mp-itn`.

I suggest you read the documentation before you do anything else. It explained this in the [selector-syntax page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).